# How can I get a Surface object from an EGLSurface?

Tags: java, android, gstreamer, grafika

I need to write a frame from a video stream to an image file. The stream is coming from a [GStreamer Player](https://github.com/sdroege/gst-player/blob/master/android/app/src/main/java/org/freedesktop/gstreamer/Player.java), so it needs to be directed to a `Surface` object (it won't accept an `EGLSurface`). However, I'm trying to use [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika)'s `OffscreenSurface` as the output so that I can call `saveFrame(File file)` to save the latest frame to a file.

So the problem is `OffscreenSurface` uses an `EGLSurface` rather than a `Surface`, so I can't set it as the output location for the stream since `Player#setSurface(Surface surface)` requires a `Surface`.

Is there a way to get a `Surface` object when creating an `EGLSurface`, or possibly when creating an `OffscreenSurface` from Grafika?

Comment: Create a SurfaceTexture, use that to construct a Surface, pass that Surface to GStreamer. Video output becomes available as a GL texture. Something like http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#ExtractMpegFramesTest .

Comment: The solution was to replace the `SurfaceView` with a `TextureView`, that way you get a `SurfaceTexture` as @fadden says